# I want to use data from the StreamBuilder outside of the StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase

I want to use data from the StreamBuilder outside of the StreamBuilder.

I want to use data inside StreamBuilder, but if I put selectedDropdown inside StreamBuilder, there is an error(?) that doesn't change dropdownButton value, so I want to use StreamBuilder data outside "StreamBuilder", but I'm not sure what to do.
I tried putting in Navigator but I couldn't solve it

My code is as follows

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class sex_controller extends StatefulWidget {

  final Function(String value) onSelected;
  sex_controller({super.key, required this.onSelected});

  @override
  State<sex_controller> createState() => _sex_controllerState();
}

final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance;

class _sex_controllerState extends State<sex_controller> {
  ///sex Controllers
  List<String> dropdownList = ['male', 'female'];
  String selectedDropdown = 'male';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('1_email', isEqualTo:currentUser.currentUser!.email).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return ListView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, i){
              var data = snapshot.data!.docs[i];

              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 5, 25, 5),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    hint: Text('sex'),
                    value: selectedDropdown,
                    focusColor: Colors.grey,
                    dropdownColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                    isExpanded: true,
                    underline: SizedBox(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 17,
                    ),
                    items: dropdownList.map((String item) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                          child: Text('$item'),
                        ),
                        value: item,
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (dynamic sex_value) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedDropdown = sex_value;
                        print(belt_value);
                      });
                      widget.onSelected(sex_value);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        } else{
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

'var data = snapshot.data!.docs[i];' How can I use  outside StreamBuilder?

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context){
                    return sex_controller(data:data, onSelected: (String value) { (){}; },);
                  },
              ),
```

I saw the code together, but I couldn't solve it
I couldn't find it in Google's place
Anyone can I help me?